# Firestore get subcollection is slow

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have collections and their sub-collections. I loop over them and collect data. It works fine but it is too slow. Can anyone suggest to improve performance issue?

```
static async getSubCategories(category_id) {
    const db = Firebase.firestore(),
        subCategories = [];
        activeRef = await db.collection("sub_categories").where("category_id", "==", category_id).orderBy("id").get();
    for (let doc of activeRef.docs) {
        const subCategory = doc.data();
        if (_.isObject(subCategory)) {
            const subRef = await doc.ref.collection('sub_sub_categories').orderBy("id").get(),
                subSubCategories = [];
            for (let subDoc of subRef.docs) {
                const subSubCategory = subDoc.data();
                if (_.isObject(subCategory)) {
                    subSubCategories.push(subSubCategory);
                    // If SubCategory has image, download storage uri
                    if (subSubCategory.image_storage_uri) {
                        const imageRef = Firebase.storage().refFromURL(subSubCategory.image_storage_uri),
                            imageUri = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
                        subSubCategory.image_uri = imageUri;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (subSubCategories.length > 0)
                subCategory.sub_sub_categories = subSubCategories;
            subCategories.push(subCategory);
        }
    }
    return subCategories;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean through "it is too slow."? How many results return your query?

Comment: I have about 30 collections and each collection has about 6-8 sub-collection doc

Comment: So how many documents in total return your query?

Comment: I've just worried that my code could be wrong...

Comment: Total collections are around 250.

Comment: I'm asking about the total number of documents and not about the total number of collections.

Comment: Sorry, total number of documents are 250

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of one of those documents.